# Protect temporary directory from hackers in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, drm

Hi I'm new in swift and XCode and have a question

I want to create an application for OS X that show some movies,images,HTML5 and...

My issue is that each files has big space(for example 200Mg) and i want to protect them from coping by others so i think that i can encrypt it and when i want to show to user, i decrypt them in temporary directory and bind them to UI but in that situation, hackers would listen to Harddisk to find my decrypted files and copy them.

I want to ask two question:

1. Do you have any other solution?
2. Is there any way to protect
       temporary directory that only my application can access it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Generally, no.  Screen recording software is included with OS X.  If you play video, any user can easily save it.

Comment: thanks for your answer. yes, but he can not get original video beside i have html5 with motions and ...

Comment: I'm not sure how you think it would work.  The user can always view any file on their hard disk.  If you're decrypting it, then it's going to exist in decrypted form.

Comment: I did it before for windows, I decrypted my files in RAM and bound result to UI like videoplayer however i can not find same solution for mac so i decided to solve my problem by directory protection

Comment: Do you think a Windows user doesn't have permission to read their own RAM?

Comment: Yes i know but we should do something that it become harder for hackers (Disk sniff vs Memory dump)

Comment: Your mistake is calling this person a "hacker" -- that typically means somebody who breaks into computers, but this person is a user, and it's their own computer.  (You wouldn't call somebody a car thief, just because they wanted to open the door of their own car.)  And whatever you try to do, there's a workaround that takes no special skills: just open Quicktime and select "New Screen Recording".  You're making the hard way harder, but there's already an easy way that you can't stop.